# Using ParameterizedTypeReference to setExpectedResponseType for HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-integration

I'm trying to configure a gateway using the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler`. The problem that I'm facing is to `setExpectedResponseType` to a generic type.

I have found some solutions when you use the `RestTemplate` directly, but when dealing with the configuration through the `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` I haven't been able to make it call the proper `exchange` method of the `RestTemplate` that receives the `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

This is the example code:

My generic class:

```
   public class ListWrapperModel<T> {

   public ListWrapperModel() {}
   private List<T> list;
}
```

My configuration for HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler:

```
    Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExp = getDefaultEndpointProperties();
    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    uriVariableExp.put("id", parser.parseExpression("payload"));

    String endpoint = "{host}/models?id={id}";
    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler gateway;

    gateway = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(endpoint, getRestTemplate());
    gateway.setRequiresReply(true);
    gateway.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    gateway.setExpectedResponseType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ListWrapperModel<Model>>(){}.getClass());
    gateway.setUriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExp);

    return gateway;
```

This is one of the scenarios that I've tried, the other one, was doing this:

```
gateway.setExpectedResponseType(new ParameterizedTypeReference<ListWrapperModel<Model>>(){}.getType().getClass());
```

But didn't work.

Debugging HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler, I notice that when it is trying to determinate the expected type, the return type is: `com.host.app.service.gateway.http.ServiceConfiguration$1`

I'm new to java but I will assume that the `$1` is the anonymous type created.

I would like to ask if there is a way to configure this so that can work properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using a response type value expression. The following settings worked for me:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<ListWrapperModel<Model>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<ListWrapperModel<Model>>() { };
gateway.setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(new ValueExpression<>(type));
```

The value expression will later be evaluated to the provided `ParameterizedTypeReference` which the underlying `RestTemplate` will use to convert the result.